# Is there a way to hide a folder from searches but can still be searched manually?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search, file-search, hidden-file

I am working on a number of manuscripts in Word using Windows 10. I have taken to storing older versions of these manuscripts in a particular folder labelled "Older Versions of Manuscript" to make sure I at least have a back-up copy if something goes wrong or I need to cross-reference with deleted sections of older drafts (and on external storage drives as well).

When I try to search for the latest draft of the manuscript using the searchbar, quite often it will give an *older* version of the manuscript and in several cases I have accidentally made corrections to older versions of the manuscript rather than the latest version. What I would like to do is deindex my "older versions of manuscripts" folder so the outdated versions of the manuscript do not appear in my search results, but I would still like to be able to search the contents of that folder specifically if I open the folder in File Explorer.

I tried hiding the folder using Indexing Options as suggested by [this link](https://www.top-password.com/blog/hide-folders-files-from-search-results-in-windows-10/), but when I opened my old manuscript folder specifically and tried to search within it it said there were no files at all. I am wondering if there is any way to deindex a folder from the system-wide search function (to keep old versions of the manuscript from popping up), but still allow the folder to be searched if a specific request is made (in case I need to find a deleted section in my old documents).

Comment: I personally would move the folder outside of the working folder. That way, if you search, it will not find the files because they are not nested in that folder.

Comment: @LPChip Already have. The issue is less the file being nested in the working folder and more when I use the searchbar to find and open the most recent version of the document, it tends to bring up older, outdated versions first even if they are in different folders and I have to sort through them all to find the one I need (or it recommends an old version as "best match").